Escaping the cycle: Route planning in graphs with conditional edges
Given a directed graph $G(V, E)$, I want to find a route, $R \in E^*$ from $S$ to $T$ for $S,T \in V$. If $G$ includes a cycle, how can I find a route that includes $n$ iterations of the cycle before following along an alternate edge?
For instance, let's assume I have the following cyclic graph: $G = \{(S,A), (A,B), (B,S), (B,T)\}$ with some arbitrary weights.

A path-finding algorithm like Djikstra's from $S$ to $T$ would give the following path: $S \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow T$. But what if the edge $(B,T)$ depends on the number of cycles traversed in the given path? This is solvable by forming a new DAG that explicitly breaks the cycle. For instance, if $(B, T)$ exists only after $n=2$ iterations of the cycle, then the solvable DAG can be written as: $G' = \{(S,A_0), (A_0, B_0), (B_0, S_1), (S_1, A_1), (A_1, B_1), (B_1, S_2), (S_2, A_2), (A_2, B_2), (B_2, T), (B_2, S_3) \}$, with the optimal path $S_0 \rightarrow A_0 \rightarrow B_0 \rightarrow S_1 \rightarrow A_1 \rightarrow B_1 \rightarrow S_2 \rightarrow A_2 \rightarrow B_2 \rightarrow T$.

Is there a way to modify a route-finding algorithm such that it treats the edge $(B, T)$ conditionally, based on the number of cycles of the graph the route has processed through? Or in order to specify such an edge do I have to break down the cycles into this far larger DAG?
Note that this is a repost from Theoretical Computer Science

repost why repost with just four hours gone by?

I posted on ThCS originally, but after a bit of reading realized the question was probably better suited for CS. My fault for not reading ahead of time.
